# C#, XNA, FileStream, Out of Memory Exception

Tags: c#, out-of-memory, xna-4.0

I'm trying to save every rendered frame of my XNA game to the harddisk. so in each frame, I call this code:

```
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            ....
            colorRT = new RenderTarget2D(GraphicsDevice, backbufferWidth, backbufferHeight, false, SurfaceFormat.Color, DepthFormat.Depth24);
            lightRT = new RenderTarget2D(GraphicsDevice, backbufferWidth, backbufferHeight, false, SurfaceFormat.Color, DepthFormat.None);
            specRT = new RenderTarget2D(GraphicsDevice, backbufferWidth, backbufferHeight, false, SurfaceFormat.Color, DepthFormat.None);

            ....
         }


        using (Stream stream = File.OpenWrite("color_"+frameNumber+".png"))
        {
            colorRT.SaveAsPng(stream, colorRT.Width, colorRT.Height);
            stream.Flush();
            stream.Close();
            stream.Dispose();
        }
        using (Stream stream = File.OpenWrite("light_" + frameNumber + ".png"))
        {
            lightRT.SaveAsPng(stream, lightRT.Width, lightRT.Height);
            stream.Flush();
            stream.Close();
            stream.Dispose();
        }
        using (Stream stream = File.OpenWrite("spec_" + frameNumber + ".png"))
        {
            specRT.SaveAsPng(stream, specRT.Width, specRT.Height);
            stream.Flush();
            stream.Close();
            stream.Dispose();
        }
        System.GC.Collect();
        frameNumber++;
```

but if this code is on, the memory consumption rises and rises and after half a minute or so i get a outOfMemory exception. I added the flush, close, dispose and GC calls to try to solve the problem, but it doesn't change a thing.

Anyone knows what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Just as an aside, the `using` statement calls Dispose for you, and neither close or flush is required if you dispose. The issue could possibly be with the fact you keep saving PNGs? Or the `xxRT` variables are growing all the time. The file streams are being rid each time properly.

Comment: yeah that's what i thoght too, but i don't see how this code then can cause outOfMemory exceptions. if i comment it out, everything runs fine

Comment: You don't need to use Flush, Close, and Dispose with *using*. Do you have any *for* loop somewhere? How is this code called? AFAIK in XNA there are methods that are called hundreds of time a second to refresh graphics. **frameNumber++** what is that? If this counter is growing then that's your problem. Move the code that loads content to a method that's called once.

Comment: @oleksii: He wants to output once each frame, so it can't just be ran once when loading content.

Comment: 'framenumber' is only used for the filenames. the code is called exactly once per frame. it's right in the end of the normal drawing routine of my scene

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/65527/515302.aspx) `Texture2D.SaveAsJpeg` (as well as `Texture2D.SaveAsPng`) has a memory leak.

The solution is (unfortunately) to create your own texture saving routine.

Comment: yap - the bmpWriter class in that thread did do the trick! thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like that if you do this for every frame (thats many per second), you're writing 3 images - there may be a queue building up to write it to disk and this is backing up the more the program runs leading to the issue.

Comment: +1 Seems plausible to me given the inability to profile it ourselves.

Comment: Perhaps try limiting the occurance of saves to once every second or so. See if that helps.

Comment: Maybe worth noting that a solution could be to limit the framerate, or don't save every frame.

Comment: when i comment out the code, it runs at arround 300 fps. with the code on, it runs only at arround 4-5 fps, so i somehow doubt that it queues up somewhere..

Comment: @Mat Assuming that isn't the problem, can you expand on what the `xxRT` variables are in your OP please? They save PNGs so could potentially have file handles and internal buffers.

Comment: @adam - i did do so. it's normal renderTargets which i use for deferred shading

Answer (score 0):

Forcing a `GC.Collect` will only collect what is eligible to be collected... and if memory pressure is high, the GC algorithm will be doing this more often for you anyway, so this is **rarely** the solution.

It also shows that you assume the `Stream s = File.Open` part is the problem. This is wrapped in a `using` statement and goes out of scope immediately afterwards, this means it is being disposed of correctly, and also will likely stay as a Gen-0 object - meaning fast, efficient collection by the GC.

You have two remaining problem areas: the `xxRT` variables that you use to call the save to PNG, and the act of saving three PNGs per frame itself.

As an aside, you can improve the formatting of the code:

```
    using (Stream stream = File.OpenWrite("color_"+frameNumber+".png"))
    using (Stream stream2 = File.OpenWrite("light_" + frameNumber + ".png"))
    using (Stream stream3 = File.OpenWrite("spec_" + frameNumber + ".png"))
    {
        colorRT.SaveAsPng(stream, colorRT.Width, colorRT.Height);
        lightRT.SaveAsPng(stream2, lightRT.Width, lightRT.Height);
        specRT.SaveAsPng(stream3, specRT.Width, specRT.Height);
    }
```

Comment: you should change the stream name... :)